# WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state- heroku django

Tags: django, heroku, websocket, daphne

I did a chatting part in my web app with django it works perfectly in local but after I deployed it to heroku , it doesn't work:
this is my consumers.py class:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Q
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async

import json

from chat.models import Thread, Message
from users.serializers import UserSerializer


class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    
    async def connect(self):
        friend = None

        me = self.scope['user']     # logged in user
        friend_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['friend']   # get the username of that user, whoom you want to chat

        friend_instance = await sync_to_async(User.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(username=friend_name)    # get user object of friend

        # create a new Thread object if thread of specific chat does not exists, otherwise return the thread
        thread = None
        try:
            thread = await sync_to_async(Thread.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)((Q(user1=me) & Q(user2=friend_instance)) | (Q(user1=friend_instance) & Q(user2=me)))
        except:
            thread = await sync_to_async(Thread.objects.create, thread_sensitive=True)(user1=me, user2=friend_instance)

        self.room_name = thread.room_name   # room name

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        '''
            disconnect the websocket connection.
        '''
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard (
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )


    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        from_user = text_data_json['user']
        to_user = text_data_json['friend']

        from_user_instanse = await sync_to_async(User.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(username=from_user['username'])    # get user object of friend
        to_user_instanse = await sync_to_async(User.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)(username=to_user['username'])    # get user object of friend

        thread_obj = await sync_to_async(Thread.objects.get, thread_sensitive=True)((Q(user1=from_user_instanse) & Q(user2=to_user_instanse)) | (Q(user1=to_user_instanse) & Q(user2=from_user_instanse)))

        message_instane = await sync_to_async(Message.objects.create, thread_sensitive=True)(messag_body=message, from_user=from_user_instanse, to_user=to_user_instanse, thread=thread_obj)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_name,
            {
                'type': 'chatroom_messages',
                'message': message_instane.messag_body,
                'user': message_instane.from_user
            }
        )


    async def chatroom_messages(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        user = event['user']

        user_serialized_data = UserSerializer(user)

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'user': user_serialized_data.data
        }))
```

in the template this is the connection request part with js:

```
chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({   //the error shows in this part that WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state 
                'message': msg,
                'user': me,
                'friend': friendName
            }));
....
/* connection request */
        const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
            'wss://'
            + window.location.host
            + '/ws/chat/'
            + friendName['username']
            + '/'
        );
```

in my chat app this I have routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers


websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<friend>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

in my project I have also routing.py

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter ({
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter (
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

and this is actually my asgi.py :

```
import os
import django #added
#from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application #removed
from channels.routing import get_default_application # added


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')
django.setup() #added
application = get_default_application() #added
#application = get_asgi_application()   #removed
```

in my procfile :

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: daphne myproject.asgi:application --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
worker: python manage.py runworker channels --settings=myproject.settings -v2
```

in my settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "myproject.routing.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
    },
}
```

it works perfectly in local but not anymore working after deployement, am I messing something

this is heroku logs :

```
......
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187913+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packa
ges/aioredis/connection.py", line 111, in create_connection
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187913+00:00 app[web.1]: reader, writer = await asyncio.wait_for(open_conne
ction(
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187916+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/ta
sks.py", line 442, in wait_for
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187916+00:00 app[web.1]: return await fut
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187916+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packa
ges/aioredis/stream.py", line 23, in open_connection
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187916+00:00 app[web.1]: transport, _ = await get_event_loop().create_conne
ction(
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187917+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/ba
se_events.py", line 1056, in create_connection
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187917+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exceptions[0]
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187917+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/ba
se_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187917+00:00 app[web.1]: sock = await self._connect_sock(
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187917+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/ba
se_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187918+00:00 app[web.1]: await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187918+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/se
lector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187918+00:00 app[web.1]: return await fut
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187918+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/asyncio/se
lector_events.py", line 537, in _sock_connect_cb
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187919+00:00 app[web.1]: raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}
')
2021-12-29T18:15:42.187919+00:00 app[web.1]: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call f
ailed ('127.0.0.1', 6379)
2021-12-29T18:15:42.188173+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-29 18:15:42,188 INFO     failing WebSocket
 opening handshake ('Internal server error')
2021-12-29T18:15:42.188439+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-29 18:15:42,188 WARNING  dropping connecti
on to peer tcp4:10.1.93.62:26296 with abort=False: Internal server error
2021-12-29T18:15:42.189132+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-12-29 18:15:42,189 DEBUG    WebSocket closed
for ['10.1.93.62', 26296]
2021-12-29T18:15:42.189195+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.93.62:26296 - - [29/Dec/2021:18:15:42] "WSDIS
CONNECT /ws/chat/person/" - -
```

Comment: Do you have an error traceback from the logs?

Comment: whenever I click send the message I get this error **WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state**

Comment: What about the logs from the Django app?

Comment: after deploying I get this error ...  in local I am not using daphne

Comment: After deploying you get what error?

Comment: whenever I click on send message I get in the console that : **WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state**

Comment: That error is from the client side JS though right? Do you not have access to the logs from the Django/daphne process in heroku?

Comment: sorry how can I view the logs from the django/daphne

Comment: Via the UI https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval-via-the-ui or the `heroku logs` command https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs apparently

Comment: thank you so much I will update my question with logs please have a look at it

Comment: Looks like the `REDIS_URL` environment variable is not found/correct so you're getting errors trying to connect to Redis. Have you set up the Heroku plugin correctly? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-redis